# How to keep old date and time when updating android db?

Tags: android, datepicker

When updating in my program, if the user does not re-enter the date into the editText boxes(one for date and the other for time) using a datapicker then the update inserts into the db the current date instead of the old one.  How would I get it to keep the old time?  Here is the code I used to enter the date and time int an int the goes into the db

```
            newTime.year = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    newTime.month = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    newTime.monthDay = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    newTime.hour = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    newTime.minute = dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    enteredTime = (int) ((newTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

Here is the code for setting the date and time when the editText are clicked on

```
public void date(View v) {
    int inType = date.getInputType(); // backup the input type
    date.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
    date.setInputType(inType);
    new DatePickerDialog(report.this, d, dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

}

public void time(View v) {
    int inType = time.getInputType(); // backup the input type
    time.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
    time.setInputType(inType);

    new TimePickerDialog(report.this, t,
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();

}

private void updateLabel() {
    date.setText(fmtDate.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
}

private void updateLabel1() {
    time.setText(fmtTime.format(dateAndTime.getTime()));
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        updateLabel();
    }
};

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        updateLabel1();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but one possibility would be the set the textboxes to what you want to be the standard. If you have a time in miliseconds (dateMillis) you can create a calendar with:

```
        Date d = new Date(dateMillis);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
```

or use a dateformatter to get the format you want:

```
        Date d = new Date(dateMillis);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    String date = formatter.format(d);
```

Comment: I am having a little trouble explaining it.  The user pick the data and time, then that data is entered into the db.  Later, goes to the same screen and update some information on the screen but not the dates.  The db is supposed to keep the old info, but the code above keep entering the current date.  Is this a better explanation?

Comment: I am guessing that dateAndTime is a Calendar, then you could set the date with dateAndTime.setTime(new Date(millis)); and the code you posted should return the old date.
If that is not it, I think you have to post more of your code, not more questions.

Comment: I added the code to how I get date and time when I click on the editTexts